# How can I search a text file for word and replace it in C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I created a text file that looks somewhat like this:

```
Hello <name>! You and <name> will go for a run in the <place>.
```

I want to replace the name variables in the file with user input and allow for repeats. For instance name may appear twice and should be able to take in different answers.

```
Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
Console.Write("Enter another name: ")
```

I realize I have to search the file and the brackets, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Use `File.ReadAllText()` to get the contents of the file, replace them and save it back like this:

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("somefile.txt"); //Change this to your file.
contents = contents.Replace("<name>", nameVariable).Replace("<place>", placeVariable);
File.WriteAllText("somefile.txt", contents);
```

You need to import the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: This is something I had thought about, but a large issue is that my text file has repeats. The "<name>" variable appears more than once and should be able to have different user input answers.

Comment: Then you should have mentioned that in your question.