# Run through a text file w/ duplicates and replace variables with user input

Tags: c#

I created a text file that looks somewhat like this:

```
Hello <name>! You and <name> will go for a run in the <place>.
```

I want to replace the name variables in the file with user input and allow for repeats. For instance `<name>` may appear twice in the text file and should be able to take in different user answers.

Any advice is appreciated.
*asked again w/ rewording

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText("mad.txt"); 
Console.Write("Enter a name: ");
string name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter a place: ");
string place = Console.ReadLine();
contents = contents.Replace("<name>", name).Replace("<place>", place);
File.WriteAllText("somefile.txt", contents);
Console.WriteLine(contents);
```

Comment: [String.replace(string oldValue, string newValue)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) is that what you are looking for?

Comment: So basicall you want to build a templating engine? What's wrong with the many kajillions of OTHER templating engines already available?

Comment: @MarcB Perhaps just out of interest.

Comment: You already asked this question here just an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870820/how-can-i-search-a-text-file-for-word-and-replace-it-in-c

Comment: I edited my question and no one replied, so the site advises you to post another question. The coding doesn't account for duplicate variables in the text file.

Comment: in essence you want to look through the textfile and find all <xyz> tags and ask for the "Please enter xyz:" and replace the appropraite occurance with the inputted value

Comment: From a strict template point of view I would expect the same thing to replace both occurrences of <name>.  What exactly is stopping you from just naming them differently, like <YourName> and <FriendsName>?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is to provide unique placeholders for a predefined number of names (in example below it's just 2, you can make more):

```
var name1 = Console.ReadLine();
var name2 = Console.ReadLine();
File.WriteAllText("somefile.txt", File.ReadAllText("mad.txt").
    Replace("<name1>", name1).Replace("<name2>", name2));
```

---

> Naming them differently would be ideal, but the instructor has not allowed that

Then your option is to create a list of names first, then search file content for the first occurrence and replace it it with first name, then for second with second name, etc.

Not very optimal but a way to do so is to `Split` string by `"<name>"` (this will remove that as a side effect) and then just create a new string where you take first index of split string and add first name to it, then second index of split and add second name, etc.

P.S.: you should write the code yourself or instructor may get angry...

Comment: he has the problem that he can have the same tag more than once and wants different values inside each of the occurances (as far as I understood he doesnt have control over the files where the tags are in)

Comment: @Thomas, I just read his comment ;)

Comment: I didnt see that one comment of his^^ (only got that impression by the question itself and the other question he has asked)

Answer (score 1):

```
Regex myreg = new Regex(@"<w+>");

string contents = File.ReadAllText("mad.txt"); 
string modifiedContents = contents;

Match m = myreg.Match(contents);   // m is the first match
while (m.Success)
{
     Console.Write("Please type in " + m.Value.Replace("<", "").Replace(">", "") + ": ");
     string place = Console.ReadLine();

     modifiedContents = myreg.Replace(contents, m.Value, place, 1);

     m = m.NextMatch();  
}
```